# Vim plugin to toggle Python function/method arguments between single- and multi-line

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a Vim plugin that can take a single-line statement like this:

```
foo = self.some_method(param1="hi", param2="there")
```

and turn it into this:

```
foo = self.some_method(
    param1="hi",
    param2="there"
)
```

Big bonus points if it can append a comma to the last argument, like this:

```
foo = self.some_method(
    param1="hi",
    param2="there",
)
```

And finally I'd like to be able to turn the multi-line version back into a single line, but just handling the single-to-multi-line scenario alone is sufficient for me. Using <kbd>J</kbd> to re-join the line is fast enough most of the time.

I'm **not** looking for a solution that formats like this:

```
foo = self.some_method(param1="hi",
                       param2="there")
```

Comment: Not a direct answer but you may want to check out my plugin: [vim-argumentative](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative)

Comment: Nice plugin. I just found and installed [sideways.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim) today, to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

With this plugin: [splitjoin.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim).
Using your example you can get something like:

```
foo = self.some_method(param1="hi", param2="there", param3="again")
```

with cursor between parenthesis, invoke using default maping `gS` :

```
foo = self.some_method(param1="hi",
        param2="there",
        param3="again")
```

to return to the original just `gJ`

It work for many languages. For python you can split dicts, lists, tuples, statements, imports

Comment: Thanks. This is very close to what I want, and I can probably modify it to work exactly how I want. Upvote for now, will accept once I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: @JimStewart Try `let g:splitjoin_python_brackets_on_separate_lines=1`